# Self Hosted SignalR Maximum connection

Tags: c#, signalr

I have created a self hosted SignalR Windows service. It is working fine, but when the connection for the client increase with the self hosted SignalR service, then some client are not able to connect, their status is shown as Connecting.

Below is the piece of code of my self hosted SignalR service:

```
  public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)

  {

OwinHttpListener listener =(OwinHttpListener)app.Properties["Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinHttpListener"];

listener.Listener.TimeoutManager.MinSendBytesPerSecond = uint.MaxValue;

listener.SetRequestQueueLimit(long.MaxValue);

listener.SetRequestProcessingLimits(Int32.MaxValue, Int32.MaxValue);

 listener.Listener.TimeoutManager.MinSendBytesPerSecond = uint.MaxValue;

      app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
      app.MapSignalR();
            }
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: please try to edit question ?

Comment: What kind of numbers are we talking about? 5 clients? 50?, 500?

Comment: The clients are in thousands .

Comment: Hi Guys any help regarding this question.. it has been so long..